# front end workflow tools and NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, frontend

as a example

- Package Manager (BOWER,GULP)
- JavaScript Task Runner(GRUNT)
- Web Scaffolding tool (Yeoman)

why theses type of front end workflow tools ONLY AVAILABLE IN NODEJS not any other language.

Comment: Maybe because they're using JS? :-)

Comment: insted of using js why there is no frontend tools like this using another languages.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect from your question? That's not clear to me...

Comment: is there any special reason behind the all these web front end workflow tools  need node package manager(nodejs) for work.

is there any other these type of web front end workflow tools available which not need node package manager for work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower,Gulp,Grunt,yoeman etc are npm packages. There are similar packages in other  languages. Here are some.

#### Front end package managers using bower repo

[bowerphp](http://bowerphp.org) - A PHP implementation of Bower.

[django-bower](https://django-bower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - python django

[bower-ruby](https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails) - use bower in ruby

#### Build tools

[phing](https://www.phing.info) -based on apache ant, [taskphp](https://taskphp.github.io) - task runner inspired from grunt and gulp, [bldr](http://bldr.io) - php

[rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org) ,[capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) - ruby (Capistrano tasks behave slightly differently than rake tasks and their hookable nature separates them from rake tasks.)

[fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) - python

This is what I understood from your question. You can always use these npm packages along with other languages also.eg [yoeman with php](https://github.com/revathskumar/yeoman-php)

Comment: why node js tools are more popular among these